# Cascade Delete on table with multiple referee with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, fluent

I've got three objects:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual Lilst<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; 
}
```

The fluent configuration for this is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(p => p.ProjectEntityID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(p => p.ProjectEntityID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasOptional(t => t.Currency).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasKey(t => t.Name)
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

The Currency class holds data that is shared in the application, so I would not like any duplicate entries in this table. I've tried to enable such a behavior, but that might be another question. What I am trying to achieve is that if I delete a record from Project, the referenced Currency should be cascade deleted, as well as the referenced Profile and its reference to its Currency record. In my example above, if I delete a Project record, its profiles and profiles currencies are deleted, but not the record referenced directly from Project.

So deleting a Project should delete these records

```
   |--Currency
   |
Project
   |
   |-- Profiles -- Currency
```

Comment: AFAIK EF will not `CASCADE DELETE` if the relation is optional so you should have `modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasRequired(t => t.Currency)`. But I fear you'll then have another issue with multiple CASCADE path. The real issue is how to uniquely identify your `Currency entities`. So fix it first and then make one of the relationship required.